# Load UISplitViewController programmatically from another Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

Currently I am using two iPad storyboards in my project.

The first storyboard has a Login screen and a tableview controller. I want to call the second storyboard from the first storyboard tableview controller, when the cell is clicked. Normally it's easy, but here the second story board has a `UISplitViewController`.

```
    MainSVC *baseView = [[MainSVC alloc] init]; //UISplitViewController

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Mail_iPad" bundle:nil]; //Second Storyboard

    baseView =[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainSVC"]; //MainSVC = Storyboard Name
    [self presentViewController:baseView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code is not working. I searched in google, but couldn't find the best solution.

How can I call second storyboard splitview controller programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code. This should be work. !

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Mail_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UISplitViewController *split = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainSVC"];
    self.view.window.rootViewController = split;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not allocate another instance of split view controller. It should be done like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Mail_iPad" bundle:nil]; //Second Storyboard

MainSVC *baseView =(MainSVC *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainSVC"]; //MainSVC = Storyboard Name
[self presentViewController:baseView animated:YES completion:nil];
```